# Internacionalization in app.config.js expo file

Tags: expo, i18n-js

I use the i18n-js lib to make internacionalization in my apps.
In Expo, there's a file app.json with the app configs.
There is a possibility to create a app.config.js to customize some things in the file.
But I can't use import to do this, to translate app name, for example.

Anyone can help me?